# How do you use this: int (*x(int))[5]

Tags: c, declaration, typedef

`int (*x(int))[5]` says x is a function that takes an `int` argument, and returns a pointer to an integer array of 5 elements.

I can also use `typedef` to simplify x:

```
typedef int Array[5];
typedef Array *Array_ptr;
typedef Array_ptr Array_ptr_fn(int);
```

My question is, how do I use this type Array_ptr_fn?

```
// Define some_x to have type Array_ptr_fn,
 
Array_ptr_fn some_x;

// But then how do I use some_x since function cannot return array.
```

Comment: Unless you're passing around functions, just declare your function directly, as in `Array_ptr someFunction(int);` Even if you're passing around functions, you can still use this declaration as a function parameter.  I don't think you need the third typedef at all; it just obfuscates.

Comment: `some_x` isn't trying to return an array. It returns a pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to note is that `x` is not a function *pointer*, but an actual function declaration. It's not a variable. A *pointer* to `x` would have the type `int (*(*ptr_to_x)(int))[5]`.

The second thing to note is that the return value of `x` is neither `int[5]`, nor `int[]`, nor `int*`, but `int (*)[5]`. That is, you need to write `(*retval)[0]` to get to an actual `int` value.

With that in mind, it's not that hard to write a proof of concept that uses these types:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int arr[5] = { 11, 22, 33, 44, 55 };
int (*ptr)[5] = &arr;

int (*x(int ignored))[5]
{
    return ptr;
}

int main(void)
{
    int (*(*ptr_to_x)(int))[5] = &x;

    int (*i)[5] = ptr_to_x(123);
    printf("%d\n", (*i)[2]);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Array_ptr_fn some_x; /* ERROR */
```

You cannot use the type `Array_ptr_fn` to define a variable... but you can use a pointer to that type to store a function reference (with that interface) to be called in the future, as in:

```
int (*f1(int))[5];  /* implemented elsewhere */

Array_ptr_fn *some_function = f1;

int (*my_array)[5] = f1(27); 
 
/* or equivalently */

int (*my_second_array)[5] = some_function(27);
```